# How to avoid iOS 13 default behavior for full screen modal in react-navigation 6

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Can we still opt-in for the old presentation behavior on iOS 13? It's useful in some cases, e.g. displaying a random quote to a user.

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-5.x#modemodal-is-removed-in-favor-of-presentation-modal

Comment: Thanks @RajendranNadar. I had read the docs earlier but by then, they hadn't updated the migration guide to explain how to achieve this.

Comment: Yes, react-navigation v6 stable was released yesterday

Comment: Yeah, I was using beta.